# Problem with a call button - doesn't open tel:// URL

Tags: iphone

I am trying to make a call button that will call 18 which is Fire Dept in France.

So my code is :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://18"]];
```

It doesn't work and I get this message in the console :

> < warning > Ignoring unsafe request to open URL tel://18

But I saw other application that have the same button fully working !

I am trying this on the device of course.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I Found the answer after wasting many hours...

**Here is the solution :**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://18?1"]];
```

The iPhone accepts the interrogation mark but ignores it when initiating the call !

In Safari, if you try this :

```
tel://18
```

It won't work but if you try this :

```
tel://18?1
```

It will call 18 !

Comment: so what about some numbers like this : `*140*1#`

Comment: IOS7 Update the tel://18?1 or tel://18#1 works well on IOS 5 & 6, but i'm not able to call a 2 digits phone number on IOS 7. Has someone a solution ?

Comment: Me too, @F.Lambert did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The correct url has no backslashes.  That is, it should be `tel:18`

Comment: Mmm It doesn't work neither. I get this in the console now :
< warning > Ignoring unsafe request to open URL tel:18

Comment: Well, that seems like it's just not letting you call that number because it knows it's an emergency number or something.  Try using a regular phone number and see if that works.  If it does, then the SDK is just set up not to let you dial 18 programmatically.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work for any combination of 2 numbers but I saw another application that could make it. I just wonder how...

Comment: I'm not familiar with non-US phone numbers, so I don't know what all of the + and # and (Wait) things mean, but have you tried putting something like a + or a - in the number that doesn't actually change the number dialed, but increases its length

Comment: Ok so I tried +, # and the only way it worked was by inserting a pause after 18 like this : "tel:18p" BUT it shows in the phone application : "18," and i would like to avoid it and have only "18"...

Answer (score 1):

tel://18?1 works fine on iOS4, but it seems that iOS5 ignores everything after the ? character and refuses to just call 18...

However, tel://18♯1 works on iOS5 (and calls number 18) but not on iOS4, so you have to switch according to the iOS version of the client.