# Call a two digits phone number with Titanium on ios7

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have to call small phone number with only two digits, when I click on a specific view. 
This is working well in Android, but this doesn't work on ios6 and 7. By the way, this is working fine with 3 digits.

This is the function I call on click :

```
$.callView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.Platform.openURL('tel:18'); 
});
```

This give me that error : 
`<Warning>: Ignoring unsafe request to open URL tel:18
<Warning>: LaunchServices: application launch failed - received error code 12`

I've seen some pieces of answer in this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625274/problem-with-a-call-button-doesnt-open-tel-url), but it's not related to Titanium.

I've tried to call `Ti.Platform.openURL` like that :

- tel://18?1
- tel:18?1
- tel:18#1
- tel:+18?1
- tel:+18#1

But none of theese things works. Have you an idea of what I have to do to make this call ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try appending a pause as in `tel:18p`. This will show up as `18,` which you might not like, but this looks like a long standing issue with Apple, so a fix doesn't appear imminent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have already try to use `tel:18p`. The problem is when I do that, and click on the button, it opens the phone, but the number is `187` instead of `18,`. It looks like ios transform the "p" character with the equivalent number "7". In one word, I'm steel looking for an answer to this problem...

Comment: Telephony requires a pause command of some sort. It's a matter of finding what it maps to. It might be as simple as using a comma.

Comment: People have had success using `tel:18;18`. I think the correct format would be something like this: `tel:18;phone-context=+2125551234`.

Comment: The latest solution works for me : `tel:18;18`, thanks. It calls the good number, but for you to know, it writes "18;18" on the phone screen.